# Why universal reference have to use template for the member function instead of class?

Tags: c++, c++11

For example:
This is *NOT* universal reference:

```
template<typename T>
class C {
  public:
    void gogo(T&& c);
};
```

But this is:

```
template<typename A>
class C {
  public:
    template<typename B>
    void gogo(B&& par);
}
```

Comment: To make it possible for you to indicate if you mean by that && to have rvalue reference or universal reference parameter in your member function of template class.

Comment: In the first case, you need to have an object of type `C<T>` in order to call the `gogo` method. The value of `T` has already been determined by the object, `gogo` has no choice in the matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second snippet, `B&& par` is not necessarily an universal reference. It's considered to be universal only if you let the compiler deduce `B` when the call is made:

```
C<float> c;
c.gogo(42); // T is deduced as int, `par` acts as an universal reference.
c.gogo<int>(42); // T is fixed, `par` is a regular rvalue reference.
```

Since in the first snippet `T` is always fixed when the call is made, the reference is never universal.

```
C<int> c; // Must specify T here, there's no way for it to be deduced.
c.gogo(42); // T is fixed, `par` is a regular rvalue reference.
```

Comment: With c++17 in the last example the type can actually be deduced if you provide a template deduction guide.

Answer (score 1):

This is because a universal, or a forwarding reference is, by definition an rvalue reference to a template parameter ***of the function call itself***.

> Deducing template arguments from a function call    [temp.deduct.call]
>
> A forwarding reference is an rvalue reference to a cv-unqualified
> template parameter that does not represent a template parameter of a
> class template

The standard explicitly calls out the fact that the template parameter is not a class template parameter. You can actually figure it out yourself:

```
template<typename T>
class C {
  public:
    void gogo(T&& c);
};
```

Here, `goto()` is not a template function. The template here is the class. Once the template class gets instantiated with some specific type, `gogo()` is just an ordinary, non-template class method that takes a parameter of a defined, specific type, an rvalue reference to whatever type the class template parameter is.

Comment: Many thanks for helping a newbie! Yes I think I was infamilar with template class.. Thanks.